# Showing that this function is self inverse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

For the following function $f : \mathbb{R^n}\setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ defined by

$f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|^2}$,     show that $f$ is its own inverse

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show $f\circ f(x) = x$, and this is quite simple: $f(f(x)) = f\left(\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}}{\left|\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}\right|^2}= \dfrac{\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}}{\dfrac{||x||^2}{||x||^4}}= \dfrac{x}{||x||^4}\cdot ||x||^4 = x$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

We can see it directly from definition: Let $x \neq 0$; let $y := f(x)$; then
$$
f(y) = \frac{y}{|y|^{2}} = \frac{x/|x|^{2}}{1} = \frac{x}{|x|^{2}}.
$$

Comment: why is this function well defined? It is not defined at $x=0$ right?

Comment: @Rise: Hey yes.

Comment: Yea, this function is not defined at  x = 0

Answer (score 0):

$f(f(x))=\frac{\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}}{\left\lvert\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}\right\rvert^2}=\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert ^2}\times\frac{\lvert x^2\rvert^2}{| x|^2}=x$.
Hence $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$